# Android List View Items Alignment

Tags: android, listview

I have a list view in which I add items dynamically. I want that some items ( of my choice) should align to the left hand side and some to the right hand side. Is this thing possible with the ListView of Android??

//Adapter

```
if (convertView == null) {
                holder = new EventViewHolder();
                if (type == 1) {
                    convertView = inflater.inflate(
                            R.layout.multi_line_list_item, null);
                    holder.mtvMessage = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.tvMessage);
                    holder.mtvMessage.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
                    holder.mtvMessage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.chatbluebox);
                    convertView.setTag(holder);
                }else{
                    convertView = inflater.inflate(
                            R.layout.multi_line_list_item, null);
                    holder.mtvMessage = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.tvMessage);
                    holder.mtvMessage.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
                    holder.mtvMessage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.chatgreenbox);
                    convertView.setTag(holder);

            }
```

Please let me know if it can be done and suggest me a good solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following.

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

And then

```
listView.setSelection(items.size()-1);
```

For gravity You need to set gravity dynamically in your `getview()` method.

FOr example :-

```
textview1.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
```

Comment: I am not able to set the gravity dear. I have edited my code for showing you the gravity matter. Please have a look.

Comment: holder.mtvMessage.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT); and right any of one not working ? or both have no effect ?

Comment: I am done with the solution. have made another layout and inflated it in other condition

Comment: Please have a look if you know.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13135823/android-service-is-not-stopping

Answer (score 5):

```
android:stackFromBottom="true"
android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"
```

Add these lines in your listView xml entry..,.

And for right and left alignment, maintain two layouts xmls one right align and other left align(Whatever look you want) and then in getView() method of listAdapter set some condition and inflate these xml as you want

```
if (convertView == null)
    if(some condition)
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.rightxml, null);
    else
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.leftxml, null);
    ....
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the ListView modes [stackFromBottom](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#attr_android%3astackFromBottom) and [transcriptMode](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#attr_android%3atranscriptMode) those may do most of the work for you.

To align the items in the Cells left and right you can, for example set the gravity to left and right in your Adapters getView Method.

Comment: Ok let me check the gravity matter. Will let you know if it is done

Comment: I am not able to set the gravity dear. I have edited my code for showing you the gravity matter. Please have a look.