# Android Service is not Stopping

Tags: android, service, android-intent, forceclose

In my application when I login I start the `UpdaterService.class` . And when I logout then the application is successfully logged out. But when I again log in then it first gives *FORCE  CLOSE* and second time when I login again *AFTER FORCE CLOSE*, then it works fine. I am not able to figure out what is the matter behind.

**Updater Service**

```
public class UpdaterService extends Service implements InvitationListener {
    private static XMPPConnection connection;
    String Friend;
    String user = "";
    String senderName ="";
    String subID="";
    int subscription = 1;


    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        // Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        super.onCreate();
    }   

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {


        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        showToast("My Service Started", 0);
        connection = getConnection();
        if (connection.isConnected()) {
            final Roster roster = connection.getRoster();
            RosterListener r1 = new RosterListener() {

                @Override
                public void presenceChanged(Presence presence) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                       //notification("changed");

                }

                @Override
                public void entriesUpdated(Collection<String> arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    //notification("entriesUpdated");
                }

                @Override
                public void entriesDeleted(Collection<String> arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    //notification("entriesDeleted");
                }


                @Override
                public void entriesAdded(Collection<String> arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Iterator<String> it = arg0.iterator();
                    if (it.hasNext()) {
                        user = it.next();
                    }
                    /*RosterEntry entry = roster.getEntry(user);
                    if(entry.getType().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("to")){
                        int index_of_Alpha = user.indexOf("@");
                        String subID = user.substring(0, index_of_Alpha);

                        notification("Hi,"+subID+" wants to add you");
                    }       */      
                }
            };

            if (roster != null) {
                System.out.println("subscription going on");
                roster.addRosterListener(r1);
            }

        } else {
            showToast("Connection lost-", 0);
        }


        //Group Chat Invitation
        MultiUserChat.addInvitationListener(connection, new InvitationListener() {

            @Override
            public void invitationReceived(Connection arg0, String arg1, String arg2,
                    String arg3, String arg4, Message arg5) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                System.out.println("Received");
                notification("Invitation Received");

            }
        });

        //presence check
        connection.addPacketListener(new PacketListener() {

            @Override
            public void processPacket(Packet arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Presence presence = (Presence)arg0;
                if(presence.getType().equals(Presence.Type.subscribe))
                {

                    user = presence.getFrom();
                    int index_of_Alpha = user.indexOf("@");
                    subID = user.substring(0, index_of_Alpha);

                    /*Roster roster = connection.getRoster();
                    RosterEntry entry = roster.getEntry(user);*/


                        notification("Hi,"+subID+" wants to add you");

                }

                if(presence.getType().equals(Presence.Type.subscribed)){

                    Roster roster = connection.getRoster();
                    RosterEntry entry = roster.getEntry(user);
                    if(entry.getType().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("to")){
                        int index_of_Alpha = user.indexOf("@");
                        subID = user.substring(0, index_of_Alpha);




                }

                }
            }
        },new PacketTypeFilter(Presence.class));

        PacketFilter filter = new MessageTypeFilter(Message.Type.chat);
        final PacketCollector collector = connection.createPacketCollector(filter);
        connection.addPacketListener(new PacketListener() {

            @Override
            public void processPacket(Packet packet) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //notification(packet.getFrom());
                packet = collector.nextResult();
                Message message = (Message)packet;
                senderName = packet.getFrom();

                int alphaPOS = senderName.indexOf("@");
                String subSenderName = senderName.substring(0,alphaPOS); 



                notificationforChat(subSenderName+": "+message.getBody(),packet.getFrom().toString());
            }
        }, filter);

         /*while (true) {
                Packet packet = collector.nextResult();
                if (packet instance of Message) {
                    Message message = (Message) packet;
                    if (message != null && message.getBody() != null)
                        System.out.println("Received message from "
                                + packet.getFrom() + " : "
                                + (message != null ? message.getBody() : "NULL"));

                    notification(""+message.getBody());

                }
            }*/

    }

    protected void showToast(String msg, int time) {
        Toast.makeText(this, msg, time).show();
    }

    private XMPPConnection getConnection() {
        return CCMStaticVariable.CommonConnection;
    }
```

Here is the code to stop the service ( **LOGOUT** code)

```
if (CCMStaticVariable.CommonConnection.isConnected()) {
                    //super.onBackPressed();

                    final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);      
                    alertDialog.setTitle("CCM Logout");
                    alertDialog.setMessage("Are you sure you want to logout?");
                    alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

                    //Ok button for Logout
                    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                            CCMStaticVariable.CommonConnection.disconnect();

                            Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(UserMenuActivity.this,UpdaterService.class);
                            stopService(serviceIntent);

                            //CCMStaticVariable.CommonConnection.removeConnectionListener(arg0);
                            finish();

                        }
                    });
```

**LOGCAT**

```
10-30 14:53:00.189: D/dalvikvm(944): GC_CONCURRENT freed 919K, 55% free 3013K/6663K, external 2582K/2706K, paused 8ms+3ms
10-30 14:53:01.248: W/dalvikvm(944): threadid=10: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
10-30 14:53:01.278: E/AndroidRuntime(944): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
10-30 14:53:01.278: E/AndroidRuntime(944): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
10-30 14:53:01.278: E/AndroidRuntime(944):  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
10-30 14:53:01.278: E/AndroidRuntime(944):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:274)
10-30 14:53:01.278: E/AndroidRuntime(944):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:125)
10-30 14:53:01.278: E/AndroidRuntime(944):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:308)
10-30 14:53:01.278: E/AndroidRuntime(944):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
10-30 14:53:01.278: E/AndroidRuntime(944):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
10-30 14:53:01.278: E/AndroidRuntime(944):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
10-30 14:53:01.278: E/AndroidRuntime(944):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
10-30 14:53:01.278: E/AndroidRuntime(944): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-30 14:53:01.278: E/AndroidRuntime(944):  at org.jivesoftware.smackx.muc.MultiUserChat$1.connectionCreated(MultiUserChat.java:114)
10-30 14:53:01.278: E/AndroidRuntime(944):  at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.initConnection(XMPPConnection.java:607)
10-30 14:53:01.278: E/AndroidRuntime(944):  at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.connectUsingConfiguration(XMPPConnection.java:556)
10-30 14:53:01.278: E/AndroidRuntime(944):  at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.connect(XMPPConnection.java:984)
10-30 14:53:01.278: E/AndroidRuntime(944):  at com.cipl.CCM.frontend.XMPPConn.checkXMPPConnection(XMPPConn.java:51)
10-30 14:53:01.278: E/AndroidRuntime(944):  at com.cipl.CCM.frontend.LoginActivity$LoginUserTask.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:135)
10-30 14:53:01.278: E/AndroidRuntime(944):  at com.cipl.CCM.frontend.LoginActivity$LoginUserTask.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:1)
10-30 14:53:01.278: E/AndroidRuntime(944):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
10-30 14:53:01.278: E/AndroidRuntime(944):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
10-30 14:53:01.278: E/AndroidRuntime(944):  ... 4 more
10-30 14:53:01.878: E/WindowManager(944): Activity com.cipl.CCM.frontend.LoginActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@4063f7f8 that was originally added here
10-30 14:53:01.878: E/WindowManager(944): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.cipl.CCM.frontend.LoginActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@4063f7f8 that was originally added here
10-30 14:53:01.878: E/WindowManager(944):   at android.view.ViewRoot.<init>(ViewRoot.java:258)
10-30 14:53:01.878: E/WindowManager(944):   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:148)
10-30 14:53:01.878: E/WindowManager(944):   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
10-30 14:53:01.878: E/WindowManager(944):   at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:424)
10-30 14:53:01.878: E/WindowManager(944):   at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:241)
10-30 14:53:01.878: E/WindowManager(944):   at com.cipl.CCM.frontend.LoginActivity$LoginUserTask.onPreExecute(LoginActivity.java:130)
10-30 14:53:01.878: E/WindowManager(944):   at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:391)
10-30 14:53:01.878: E/WindowManager(944):   at com.cipl.CCM.frontend.LoginActivity$1.onClick(LoginActivity.java:62)
10-30 14:53:01.878: E/WindowManager(944):   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
10-30 14:53:01.878: E/WindowManager(944):   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
10-30 14:53:01.878: E/WindowManager(944):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
10-30 14:53:01.878: E/WindowManager(944):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-30 14:53:01.878: E/WindowManager(944):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
10-30 14:53:01.878: E/WindowManager(944):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
10-30 14:53:01.878: E/WindowManager(944):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-30 14:53:01.878: E/WindowManager(944):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
10-30 14:53:01.878: E/WindowManager(944):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
10-30 14:53:01.878: E/WindowManager(944):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
10-30 14:53:01.878: E/WindowManager(944):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

LoginActivity

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity {
    /** Variable define here. */
    private EditText metLoginUserName, metLoginPassword;
    private Button mbtnLogin;
    private ImageView ivRegister;
    private String Host, username, password;
    private int Port;
    private UserChatActivity xmppClient;
    public static ArrayList<String> all_user = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static CustomProgressDialog mCustomProgressDialog;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.loginlayout);

        metLoginUserName = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.etLoginUserName);
        metLoginPassword = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.etLoginPassword);
        mbtnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
        ivRegister = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivRegister);

        /** Set the hint in username and password edittext */
        metLoginUserName = CCMStaticMethod.setHintEditText(metLoginUserName,
                getString(R.string.hint_username), true);
        metLoginPassword = CCMStaticMethod.setHintEditText(metLoginPassword,
                getString(R.string.hint_password), true);

        /** Click on login button */
        mbtnLogin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                /** Login Activity */
                username = metLoginUserName.getText().toString();
                password = metLoginPassword.getText().toString();
                CCMStaticVariable.musername = username;
                CCMStaticVariable.musername = password;
                if(CCMStaticMethod.isInternetAvailable(LoginActivity.this)){
                    LoginUserTask loginUserTask = new LoginUserTask(v.getContext());
                    loginUserTask.execute();
                }
            }
        });

        /** Click on forgot button */
        this.findViewById(R.id.ivForgot).setOnClickListener(
                new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this,
                                ForgotPassActivity.class));
                    }
                });

        /** Click on register button */
        ivRegister.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this,
                        RegisterActivity.class));
            }
        });
    }

    public class LoginUserTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, XMPPConnection> {
        public LoginUserTask(Context context) {
            super();
            this.context = context;
        }
        private Context context;

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(XMPPConnection result) {
            if (result != null) {
                /**Start services*/
                startService(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, UpdaterService.class));
                /**Call user menu activity*/    
                //finish();

                LoginActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this,UserMenuActivity.class));

                    }
                });

            } else {
                DialogInterface.OnClickListener LoginUnSuccessOkAlertListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    }
                };
                CCMStaticMethod.showAlert(context, "Login",
                        "Invalid Username or Password. Try Again !", R.drawable.unsuccess,
                        true, true, "Ok", LoginUnSuccessOkAlertListener, null,
                        null);
            }
            mCustomProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            mCustomProgressDialog = CustomProgressDialog.createDialog(
                    LoginActivity.this, "", "");
            mCustomProgressDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected XMPPConnection doInBackground(Void... params) {
            CCMStaticVariable.CommonConnection = XMPPConn.checkXMPPConnection(username,
                    password);
            return CCMStaticVariable.CommonConnection;
        }
    }
```

Please let me know what is my mistake or how it can be solved??

Comment: How do you know that the service is not being stopped?

Comment: @KumarBibek I think so it is happening because of the service. Please help me if I am wrong

Comment: Log something in your service's onDestroy method, and check if it's getting printed in the Logcat. Your logs suggest, that you are leaking the activity. Before finishing the activity, try dismissing the dialog, or check where you are passing the activity's reference.

Comment: I think you are moving in a wrong direction.Here in this line it reflects the error when i Login again..

@Override
  protected XMPPConnection doInBackground(Void... params) {
   CCMStaticVariable.CommonConnection = XMPPConn.checkXMPPConnection(username,
     password);
   return CCMStaticVariable.CommonConnection;
  }

Comment: please post the code of the LoginActivity.. It looks like you are leaking a window there..

Comment: @PrafulBhatnagar Please have a look. I have added the code for the Login Activity

Comment: Did you check the value of username and password are they non null?

Comment: I found a useful post discussing the same topic. Please have a look http://code.google.com/p/asmack/issues/detail?id=13

Comment: @PrafulBhatnagar Yes username and password are not null.